# Install MongoDB on x86 Windows, BayTrail processor?

Tags: windows-8.1, asus-laptop, mongodb

I encountered this recently. I have been installing MongoDB on several computers/laptops without any problem.

I tried to install MongoDB using this file mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.8-signed.msi on my laptop ASUS X205TA, x32 windows, x64 BayTrail processor, windows 8.1 but I cannot install it.

It pops up an error saying:

> The installer is not supported by my processor, contact vendor.

Is there a more compatible installer and older version that might fit better?

Comment: **All 32-bit and 64-bit hardware can run 32-bit software.**  So your error has nothing to do with your hardware.  This error is caused by attempting to run 64-bit hardware on a 32-bit version of Windows.

Comment: I have confirmed you are attempting to download the 64-bit installer, but you are clearly running, a 32-bit version of Windows.  So download the [32-bit installer](https://www.mongodb.com/dr/fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.8-signed.msi/download) instead.